# JSON not parsing using PHP

Tags: php, json

My json is

```
{"productInfoList":[{"prod":"Some Products","price":"someprice"},{"prod":"Another Product","price":"48"}]}
```

My php code is

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,  'http://example.com/file.json');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$voo = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$yf= json_decode($voo,true); 
for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++)
{
$fkname = $yf->{'productInfoList'}[$i]->{'prod'};
echo $i;

echo $fkname;
}
?>
```

Output is `012345`. How can I get product names using json?
The json file is totally fine I checked it using http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `json_decode`, the json is converted to a php array.Try replacing this line:

```
$fkname = $yf->{'productInfoList'}[$i]->{'prod'};
```

With this line:

```
$fkname = $yf['productInfoList'][$i]['prod'];
```

Here is a working **[DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn%20$yourJson%20=%20'%7B%22productInfoList%22:[%7B%22prod%22:%22Some%20Products%22,%22price%22:%22someprice%22%7D,%7B%22prod%22:%22Another%20Product%22,%22price%22:%2248%22%7D]%7D';%5Cn%20$yf=%20json_decode($yourJson,true);%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn%5Ctfor%20($i=0;%20$i%20%3C%20sizeOf($yf['productInfoList']);%20$i%20%20%20)%5Cn%5Ct%7B%5Cn%5Ct$fkname%20=%20$yf['productInfoList'][$i]['prod'];%5Cn%5Ct%5Cn%5Ct%5Ctecho%20$fkname.%22%3CBR%20/%3E%22;%5Cn%5Ct%7D%5Cn?%3E%5Cn)**

> **Code Improvement**
>   In your loop, use the array size instead of hard-coding the length:

```
for ($i=0; $i < sizeOf($yf['productInfoList']); $i++)
{
$fkname = $yf['productInfoList'][$i]['prod'];

    echo $fkname."<BR />";
}
```

Comment: Great but if I remove true then?

Comment: Ok you were faster than gonzalon so you win the checkmark, upvoted both.

Comment: @IdidntKnewIt please check the demo for your code improvement

Comment: @IdidntKnewIt sorry i had a typo in my demo, please check it again

Comment: @IdidntKnewIt the browser is removing my `i++` in the demo i provide, please edit it before you run it

Answer (score 2):

Like this would work:

```
$yf= json_decode($voo,true); 

$arr = $yf['productInfoList'];

for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($arr); $i++)
{
$fkname = $arr[$i]['prod'];
echo $i;

echo $fkname;
}
```

Take in count the `sizeof` function for iterating over an array.

The output would be:

> 0Some Products1Another Product

Answer (score 1):

use `foreach` and its simple

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,  'http://example.com/file.json');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$voo = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$yf= json_decode($voo,true); 

$i = 0;
foreach($yf['productInfoList'] as $product)
{    
    echo $i.' - '.$product['prod'].'<br />';
    $i++;
}
?>
```